# File IO speed difference between Windows and Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, file-io

I am developing python2 application for both Unix and Windows operating systems, which may generate a somewhat large number of output files upon user request (e.g. 50k files). During testing, I noticed that the output generation task took an exceedingly large amount of time to finish on Windows, when compared to the same task on Linux.

So I did a little benchmarking by generating and writing some random text to 50k files and then removing those files on Windows and Linux (I have a machine with dual boot of Windows 10 and Archlinux, so the following code was executed in the same machine).

```
import os
from os.path import join

str_to_write = "a"*500

tdir = "temp"

def create_files():
    os.makedirs(tdir)

    for i in xrange(50000):
        with open(join(tdir, "{}.txt".format(i)), "w") as fh:
            fh.write(str_to_write)

def remove_files():
    for i in os.listdir(tdir):
         os.remove(join(tdir, i))
```

### Results

#### Linux

```
%time create_files()
Wall time: 896 ms
%time remove_files()
Wall time: 555 ms
```

#### Windows

```
%time create_files()
Wall time: 1min 18s
%time remove_files()
Wall time: 21.4 s
```

I noticed that the real time checking of Windows defender was turned on by default on Windows 10, but even after turning it off:

```
# Windows defender real-time check off
%time create_files()
Wall time: 27.5 s
%time remove_files()
Wall time: 17.5 s
```

Is this completely attributable to the differences in filesystems (NTFS vs Ext4)? Is there anything that can be done to decrease the time to generate many output files on Windows that can be easily distributed?

EDIT: Forgot to mention that these benchmarks were executed on a NVMe M.2 SSD.

Comment: Was anything else using the disk at the time?

Comment: Not that I was aware off. Both benchmarks were done after a system restart and nothing else was open.

Comment: I make that 1.5ms per file, or 0.6ms with Defender disabled, which doesn't seem unusually slow to me.  The difference between Windows and Linux is probably due to fact that Windows sorts directory entries alphabetically.  I assume Python has a zip library, perhaps you should consider generating a single zip file rather than 50,000 individual files?

Comment: Is it still the same with a sync call before leaving the function? The Linux kernel may caches the write commands, returns the syscall and work on them in the background. a `os.sync()` at the end of a function may change this.